# Make actor action MoveTo not to stop on point

Tags: java, android, libgdx, actor

I have a code where i move an actor from point A to point B, i don't want it to stop on point B but to keep moving forward at the same direction exactly, i don't know how to do it.
also i want it to move in a fixed speed no matter what is the distance between the points,  can someone help?

the action is:

```
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {

        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

            touchposx = screenX;
            touchposy = screenY;

            MoveToAction action = new MoveToAction();
            action.setPosition(touchposx+300, screenHeight-touchposy+300);
            action.setDuration(5f);
               bullet.addAction(action);


            return true;
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: You want it to move to infinity or how far?

Comment: to move until it goes out from the screen

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this by using a combination of moveBy (for fixed speed), sequencing actions and a Remove Action.

But in my opinion, an Action is a too complicated approach to solve this. Actions are mainly designed for UI animations. Instead, I would override the bullet's act() method, use setPosition and remove the Actor from the stage when it left the screen.